# How to detect subscript numbers in an image using OCR?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using `tesseract` for OCR, via the `pytesseract` bindings. Unfortunately, I encounter difficulties when trying to extract text including subscript-style numbers - the subscript number is interpreted as a letter instead.

For example, in the basic image:

[image]

I want to extract the text as "CH3", i.e. I am not concerned about knowing that the number `3` was a subscript in the image.

My attempt at this using `tesseract` is:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('test.jpeg')

# Note that I have reduced the region of interest to the known 
# text portion of the image
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(
    img[200:300, 200:320], config='-l eng --oem 1 --psm 13'
)
print(text)
```

Unfortunately, this will incorrectly output

```
'CHs'
```

It's also possible to get `'CHa'`, depending on the `psm` parameter.

I suspect that this issue is related to the "baseline" of the text being inconsistent across the line, but I'm not certain.

How can I accurately extract the text from this type of image?

**Update - 19th May 2020**

After seeing Achintha Ihalage's answer, which doesn't provide any configuration options to `tesseract`, I explored the `psm` options.

Since the region of interest is known (in this case, I am using EAST detection to locate the bounding box of the text), the `psm` config option for `tesseract`, which in my original code treats the text as a single line, may not be necessary. Running `image_to_string` against the region of interest given by the bounding box above gives the output

```
CH

3
```

which can, of course, be easily processed to get `CH3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do apply pre-processing to your image before feeding it into `tesseract` to increase the accuracy of the OCR. I use a combination of `PIL` and `cv2` to do this here because `cv2` has good filters for blur/noise removal (dilation, erosion, threshold) and `PIL` makes it easy to enhance the contrast (distinguish the text from the background) and I wanted to show how pre-processing could be done using either... (use of both together is not 100% necessary though, as shown below). You can write this more elegantly- it's just the general idea.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance


img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')

def cv2_preprocess(image_path):
  img = cv2.imread(image_path)

  # convert to black and white if not already
  img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  # remove noise
  kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
  img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
  img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

  # apply a blur 
  # gaussian noise
  img = cv2.threshold(cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (9, 9), 0), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

  # this can be used for salt and pepper noise (not necessary here)
  #img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(cv2.medianBlur(img, 7), 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 31, 2)

  cv2.imwrite('new.jpg', img)
  return 'new.jpg'

def pil_enhance(image_path):
  image = Image.open(image_path)
  contrast = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image)
  contrast.enhance(2).save('new2.jpg')
  return 'new2.jpg'


img = cv2.imread(pil_enhance(cv2_preprocess('test.jpg')))


text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

Output:

```
CH3
```

The `cv2` pre-process produces an image that looks like this:
[image]

The enhancement with `PIL` gives you:

[image]

In this specific example, you can actually stop after the `cv2_preprocess` step because that is clear enough for the reader:

```
img = cv2.imread(cv2_preprocess('test.jpg'))
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

output:

```
CH3
```

But if you are working with things that don't necessarily start with a white background (i.e. grey scaling converts to light grey instead of white)- I have found the `PIL` step really helps there.

Main point is the methods to increase accuracy of the `tesseract` typically are:

1. fix DPI (rescaling)
2. fix brightness/noise of image
3. fix tex size/lines
   (skewing/warping text)

Doing one of these or all three of them will help... but the brightness/noise can be more generalizable than the other two (at least from my experience).

Answer (score 4):

This is because the font of subscript is too small. You could resize the image using a python package such as `cv2` or `PIL` and use the resized image for OCR as coded below.

```
import pytesseract
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=2, fy=2)  # scaling factor = 2

data = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(data)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
CH3
```

Comment: Scaling is one of several things I would try, and it seems to work here but might not work for every image. Additional steps include playing with dilation and training the model specifically with a set of subscript characters.

Comment: Thanks. A general solution would be preferred. @MattL. Would you be able to expand on your suggested additional steps in an answer?

Comment: A general solution would be to train a CNN model with  (possibly) 1000s of images containing normal and subscript fonts. You can also achieve a better accuracy with transfer learning by training a ResNet or VGGNet architecture with your own data. Obviously, these are more tedious.

Answer (score 2):

I think this way can be more suitable for the general situation.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
from pathlib import Path

image = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # (suitable for sharper black and white pictures
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]  # is OpenCV2.4 or OpenCV3
result_list = []
for c in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 200:
        detect_area = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        # detect_area = cv2.GaussianBlur(detect_area, (3, 3), 0)
        predict_char = pytesseract.image_to_string(detect_area, lang='eng', config='--oem 0 --psm 10')
        result_list.append((x, predict_char))
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), thickness=2)

result = ''.join([char for _, char in sorted(result_list, key=lambda _x: _x[0])])
print(result)  # CH3


output_dir = Path('./temp')
output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
cv2.imwrite(f"{output_dir/Path('image.png')}", image)
cv2.imwrite(f"{output_dir/Path('clean.png')}", thresh)
```

## MORE REFERENCE

I strongly suggest you refer to the following examples, which is a useful reference for OCR.

1. [Get the location of all text present in image using opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59785890/get-the-location-of-all-text-present-in-image-using-opencv)
2. [Using YOLO or other image recognition techniques to identify all alphanumeric text present in images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60275455/using-yolo-or-other-image-recognition-techniques-to-identify-all-alphanumeric-te)

[image]